# "gatsby-plugin-purgecss" added all used CSS of every page to all pages, there is a way to prevent that?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I m using the Bulma framework I have added "gatsby-plugin-purgecss" to remove unused CSS, it is working fine but when I take a look at the pages in the public folder all CSS is the same on all pages.

how to make it add only the CSS used by the same page, i have about 22k page and every page have his style CSS.

example: I m using className="table" on the home page but I m never use it on the other pages, I have seen that all page include ".table" CSS.
there is a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems there:

1. The wrong style importation
2. The purge of the CSS

The first one should be fixed with a standard folder and importation structure. Let's say you have a homepage that extends from the `layout.js`. In that case, your `table` styles should be in a CSS that is only imported in your homepage. So:

- Create a `homepage.css` inside a `styles` folder
- Add your `table` styles in `homepage.css`
- Import the styles only in the `index.js` page. If you add the styles in the layout or some other shared component, your styles will be imported in every component and in every page that is using the file, creating a wasting of compilation and computation time.

Once you've fixed the first issue, you can focus on the second one. If not, you are trying to add a kind of logic to your plugin, making it know in what page should or shouldn't purge the styles. [`gatsby-plugin-purgecss`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-purgecss/) adds a bunch of options to whitelisting or ignore some files and folders:

```
{ 
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-purgecss`,
  options: {
    // whitelist: ['whitelist'], // Don't remove this selector
    // ignore: ['/ignored.css', 'prismjs/', 'docsearch.js/'], // Ignore files/folders
    // purgeOnly : ['components/', '/main.css', 'bootstrap/'], // Purge only these files/folders
  }
}
```

In the `ignore` and `purgeOnly` arrays you can include the desired folders to ignore or the opposite, to force the purging (note the directory structure).

Comment: Thanks for this information it is helpful, but i m using bulma framework not my css do it is hard to splitting the css bulma there no athor way?

Comment: You can point `node_modules` with the plugin by: `purgeOnly: ['/mainstyles.css', 'node_modules/bootstrap']`. However, the logic behind this will purge everything.

Comment: by the way, I have make some CSS page like you told my and import to homepage only, but all page have the CSS of the home page.

Comment: You must be importing that style to other pages. If the homepage is standalone, it's impossible that the other pages/templates share styles.

Comment: i have import the style to homePAge not the layout but its seen that Global CSS imported on one page gets imported on all pages. i read about that issue https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14333 but no fixed solution, i need to make many Layout i think.